# PHP PDO stored procedure gives back true every time

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a stored procedure in mysql, that gives back some records, when I run it in phpmyadmin, but gives back allways a true if I try to run in PHP. Here is my stored procedure, and my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp`() NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER SELECT * FROM dataTabe


$conn = Database::connect();//It works!
if($conn != null){
 $result = $conn->query($query);//$query = 'CALL sp()';
 foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
  print_r($key);
  print_r($value);
 }
}
```

Can you help me? Thanx!

Comment: I tested your code and it works (using my connection object and settings). I suspect: 1) You have a problem with the content, the text of the created procedure in the db, in conjunction with eventual settings regarding procedures in your mysql client (phpmyadmin), or 2) You have a problem with the connection settings of your `$conn` object, or 3) There is something wrong with table `dataTabe`. On the other hand, even if it's possible, you shouldn't directly iterate through the returned object `$result`, which is of type [PDOStatement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

Comment: Instead you should use the methods which the PDOStatement class puts on your disposal. For example like this: `$result = $conn->query($query); $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); foreach ($data as $key => $value) { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: That's right!, Thank you!